# Django date picker range Javascript post

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, django

i'm trying to user Date Picker Range from http://www.daterangepicker.com/ and i have this on my html:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
    $('input[name="daterange"]').daterangepicker({
        locale:
        {
            format: 'DD/MM/YYYY '
        },
        ranges:
        {
           'Hoy': [moment(), moment()],
           'Ayer': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
           'Ultimos 7 dias': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
           'Ultimos 30 dias': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
           'Este Mes': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
           'Mes pasado': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
        }
    });
    $(window).scroll(function()
    {
        if ($('input[name="daterange"]').length)
        {
            $('input[name="daterange"]').daterangepicker("close");
        }
    });

});


    </script>

<form action="{% url 'subestados' %}" method="post">
    <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
        <label>Rango:  </label>
        <input type="text" name="daterange" class="form-control"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

my urls.py:

```
 url(r'^subestados/$',se.tabla, name='subestados'),
 url(r'^subestados/(?P<yearb>[0-9]{4})/(?P<monthb>[0-9]{2})/(?P<dayb>[0-9]{2})/(?P<yearf>[0-9]{4})/(?P<monthf>[0-9]{2})/(?P<dayf>[0-9]{2})/$',se.tabla, name='subestados'),
```

I've seen other post about this, but i can't find a solution that works for me,
i understand there is a ajax method to make the post but i don't know how to implement it:

```
$.ajax({
   url:'/',
   type : "POST", 
   data: {start : 'start', end : 'end'},
   success: function(response){},
   complete: function(){},
   error: function(xhr, textStatus, thrownError){}
   });
```

The javascript works i can see the calendar and all the options but can't find the way to do what i want.

Any clues about this ?

Comment: Show us your view if you want to send data with post

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly suggest to you to read some books or resources regarding web request types, also Django tutorial

Your JavaScript is trying to send parameters through body of the request but on the Django side you are trying to get them in the URL, to be even more wrong your URL on back-end is collecting parameters as separate month day year through URL but JavaScript side anticipates you having only 2 parameters.